# iPhone DrillDown

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hai all. I have a tableView which lists the contents of my document directory. I have some zip files in that. If I touch a file in the tableView, the corresponding zip file is unzipped and extracted in a temporary directory(`NSTemporaryDirectory()`).

The problem is how to navigate the contents which I extracted in a tableView. If suppose, the extracted zip file contains folders, I should able to view them in a tableView. Actually the flow should be like a DrillDown.

I can able to extract the zip files, but problem is, have to navigate them in a tableView. Please give me some ideas or some source codes which helps my problem.

This is my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` part,

```
NSString *filePath = //filePath;

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {

NSLog(@"File exists at path: %@",filePath);         

} else {            

NSLog(@"File does not exists at path: %@", filePath);       
}               
NSString *tmpDir =NSTemporaryDirectory();       
ZipArchive *zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
BOOL result = NO;
if([zip UnzipOpenFile:filePath]) {
    //zip file is there
    if ([zip UnzipFileTo:tmpDir overWrite:YES]) {

    //unzipped successfully

    NSLog(@"Archive unzip Success");

    result= YES;
} else {

    NSLog(@"Failure To Extract Archive, maybe password?");
    }

} else  {
    NSLog(@"Failure To Open Archive");
    }       
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:tmpDir isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {

    NSLog(@"Its Folder");
    //Prepare to tableview.             
    RootViewController *rvController =[[RootViewController     alloc]initWithNibName:@"RootViewController"bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];
}
```

But its not working. Its pushing the same contents in the document directory in the tableView

Please help me..

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where do you tell your `RootViewController` to open a new path? For me it looks like you open the same `RootViewController` again with the old path so it's sure to open the same path again

Comment: Ya. I am calling the RootViewController inside the RootViewController itself. Then whatelse should I do?

Comment: No thats not what I mean, its ok to call yourself but where do you tell the new path? have you a variable for example rvController.myPath = @"my/new/path"; and then in your RVC init method you read the myPath var and display all your content in that path

Answer (score 1):

You should add a property for setting the current file path to your controller class.
You can write a designated initializer like:

```
- (id)initWithDirectoryPath:(NSString*)path {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"DirectoryViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.directoryPath = path;
        self.navigationItem.title = [path lastPathComponent];
    }
}
```

Then you can create your view controller and push it on the navigation controller with:

```
DirectoryViewController *viewController = [[DirectoryViewController alloc] initWithDirectoryPath:path];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];    
[viewController release];
```

Don't forget to release the VC!